# Ruby space character does not equal space character

Tags: ruby, string

In the following statements, one of the spaces is from a user's input (I copied the user's character from a remote Rails Console (an ActiveRecord field), and pasted it), and the other is from my keyboard. The statements return `false`:

```
" " == " " # => false
" ".include? " " # => false
```

Any ideas on why/how this might be happening?

Comment: Try checking them `[" ".ord, " ".ord]`, if you get `[32, 160]`, you have a whitespace and a non-breaking whitespace.

Comment: UTF-8 or non-printing characters, possibly. Just because it looks like a space doesn’t mean it is. Another reason to never trust user input!

Comment: Sebastian - that is it, I figured it must be some sort of encoding issue.  Thanks.

Comment: _“I figured it must be some sort of encoding issue”_ —this is by no mean an encoding issue. The user typed a non-breakable space. Smart people tune their keyboards nowadays to be able to type typographically correct stuff, like proper “quotes” and ‘apostrophes’ instead of typewriter’s crap. Also spaces, en–dashes, em—dashes, and even hearts ❤.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @sawa SO parser converts whatever space to the normal ASCII, so there is no way to paste it properly here. Although, the issue is well described.

Comment: @mudasobwa I see.

Comment: @sawa sorry, not whatever space :) only nbsp. Spaces from my answer are preserved. I will change the OP to one of those to make the problem reproducible. → here you go, it’s now reproducible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To validate user input for *blankness*, one should not use `==` and/or `include?` helpers. One should use the modern regular expression, that matchees *spaces*.

FYI: there are more than ten whitespace characters in UTF-8 specs, including, but not limited to:

```
spaces = {
  space_medium_mathematical_space: " ",
  spaces_em_quad: " ",
  spaces_em_space: " ",
  spaces_en_quad: " ",
  spaces_en_space: " ",
  spaces_figure_space: " ",
  spaces_four_per_em_space: " ",
  spaces_hair_space: " ",
  spaces_punctuation_space: " ",
  spaces_six_per_em_space: " ",
  spaces_thin_space: " ",
  spaces_three_per_em_space: " "
}
```

To match them, one uses [`\p{Space}`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties) matcher.

```
spaces.values.map { |s| s == ' ' }
#⇒ [false, false, false, false, false, false,
#   false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

But:

```
spaces.values.map(&/\A\p{Space}*\z/.method(:match?))
#⇒ [true, true, true, true, true, true,
#   true, true, true, true, true, true]
```

Comment: Nitpick alert: You meant Unicode specs. UTF-8 doesn't say that e.g. 8200 is a space, just that one should use bytes 226, 128 and 136 to represent it.

Comment: https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode11.0.0/ch06.pdf (p. 264) contains a table with the available spaces and some description.

Comment: @Amadan indeed. FWIW: the spaces snippet above is taken from my Elixir pet project [`StringNaming`](https://hexdocs.pm/string_naming/StringNaming.html) where I parse http://www.unicode.org/Public/10.0.0/ucd/NamesList.txt from Unicode specs to get names and values.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can utilize the [String#unicode_normalize](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/unicode_normalize/rdoc/String.html#method-i-unicode_normalize). It has several normalization forms that are documented at [unicode.org](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/). Seems like `:nfkc` and `:nfkd` suit this purpose.

```
s = "foo bar" # <-- includes a non breaking space
space = " "   # <-- regular space

s.include?(space)                          # => false
s.unicode_normalize(:nfkc).include?(space) # => true
```

Comment: I had a very strange error where some kind of hidden non-breaking space was being converted into the Euro currency symbol € when rendering the string into a PDF form field. `s.unicode_normalize(:nfkc)` solved this for me, thank you!